# Unwanted output audio looping through input

Tags: sound, xubuntu, microphone

I have a fresh Xubuntu install and I'm trying to configure the sound,

I've got a Creative Xfi Titanium series sound card

At the moment when I'm talking online in Mumble/Skype/Teamspeak etc..
my output audio is passed out as well as my input, i.e. if I was listening to music the people listening to me would also hear the music (not through my microphone, wearing a headset) and it will completely down out my voice.

Sound Input

[image]

As you can see I've disabled the monitor which I initially thought was the problem

All my searches for trying to solve this just turn up people wanting to hear their microphone through their speakers and not about a sound loop going the other way.

Comment: I've already gone through all the profiles and each one (which has input) has the same problem, thanks though

Comment: I had a similar problem on windows and solved it by creating a virtual audio device and routed the desired input and output through it to separate the audio mix. I have no idea how to do it on Linux, someone more knowledgeable should be able to set something like this up for you.

Comment: I've got Windows installed on the same machine and don't have that issue with this card mind, thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulse Audio GUI is not able to manage physical inputs and outputs. So you should try with  alsamixer and one of its GUI (ex: gnome-alsamixer). This way, you can manage the physical i/o of your sound card.

```
sudo apt-get install alsamixer gnome-alsamixer
```

Using alsamixer (in terminal) go to input (F4) and turn down the PCM volume level to 0

Note: To stop hearing your own microphone in your headset/speakers turn down the microphone level to 0 on Output (F3)

Comment: But I don't have gnome, I have Xfce, will that make a difference?

Comment: I used Gnome Alsa mixer with Ubuntu Studio, and it has XFCE desktop.

Comment: Nope, GUI crashes on start, I can run the alsamixer in teriminal however

Comment: Thanks ttoine +50 +10 for the original answer. My system does the same sort of crash as sams with Alsa.